# What is this structure called in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In this sample code:

```
const Button = props => {
  const { kind, ...other } = props;
  const className = kind === "primary" ? "PrimaryButton" : "SecondaryButton";
  return <button className={className} {...other} />;
};
```

on the second line, what is the {  } referred to in Javascript, so that I can go and look it up and understand how it works. Unfortunately, no example like this exists in the official docs for const:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

> The **destructuring assignment** syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.